# Frequently creating new producers for producing messages - can it lead to high memory usage at Kafka brokers?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am using Amazon AWS Lambda functions to produce messages to a Kafka cluster. As I can not control how frequently a Lambda function is initiated/invoked and I can not share object between invocations - I have to create a new Kafka producer for each invocation and clean it up after the invocation finishes. Each producer also set to the same "client.id".

I notice that after deploying the lambda functions the heap size at the brokers increases quickly - which finally resulted GC problems and problems at the brokers. It is very likely that this increase is connected to the Lambda producers.

I know that it is recommended to reuse single producer instance for message production. But in this case (with AWS Lambda) this is not possible.

My question is that if it is possible that high number of producer creation/cleanup can lead to memory leaks at the brokers?

Kafka cluster with 5 brokers - version 1.0.1. Kafka client lib tested with versions 0.11.0.03, 1.0.1 and 2.3.0.

Comment: I'd start by confirming that https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-6529 is fixed in your version.

Comment: @mazaneicha Our Kafka cluster is in the version 1.0.1. The producer is using java client 1.0.1 (also tested with version 2.3.0).  According to KAFKA-6529 the bug should be fixed in this version.

Answer (score 0):

every producer would need to fetch the metadata for the topic youre trying to produce to (to figure out which broker leads what partition).
then you'd send a single record (i assume) using that producer.
then you'd need to flush() + close() it (gracefully, or other side effects may happen, especially if youre using transactions and/or "exactly once").

the extra overhead in your case would be due to:

1. socket re-establishment (i dont know what youre using for authentication so i dont know how expensive this is for you)
2. fetching the metadata for the topic. depending on how bif the topic is (in terms of how many partitions across how many brokers) this may be bigger than the payload youre sending.
3. composing a record batch of size 1, with a single record in it. kafka was designed to work best in small batches, where clustering multiple small payloads gives you better compression. if your payloads are small, you may even want to disable compression completely for your case.
4. (same cause as 3) many small requests are more expensive than a single bigger one
5. (again same cause as 3) your footprint on disk is bigger due to low compression gains (or maybe even negative compression gains ...)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I believe we can make some optimisations in this context to alleviate the problem. However I am still wondering if/why creating/cleaning up producers frequently can lead to memory leaks. Our experience is that even after we stopped the applications and waited for more than one week. The heap size is still much high than before.